# Citrix always requires two launches before it appears

Tags: citrix-receiver

I had noticed an odd behaviour when using Citrix on my machine to connect to a customer's system: when double-clicking to open a remote-linked app (SQL Manager in this case) the first attempt would cause the icon on the Citrix application list to spin for a while and then... nothing. A second double-click would always work.

I thought nothing of it until today, when my coworker asked me about the same problem. However, he's seeing it on a totally different system connecting to an entirely different app being run by a different company in a different country.

No errors are reported, I can't see anything in logs, any advice on where to look?